# Which collection to use for indexing and sorting using different properties?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, collections

I would like to use/create a collection in Python, which is able to:

- Be indexed in O(1) with a key - like a hashmap
- It should be fast for getting the 1st n elements, where the 'first n' is defined by a sorting, but this sorting is not defined on the keys.

Example:

Elements:

```
['asd123', 10.1, 1100]
['esd234', 11.1, 1300]
['itd345', 12.1, 900]
```

I would like to store elements like this, where I am able to get each element by its id (1st property), and also, I'd like to be able to get the first n biggest/smallest, sorted by the second property (so basically this should be a custom sorted list, but on top it should have an index structure by id).

How can I most easily achieve this in Python3?

Comment: Store your items in a linked list sorted by the second property and have a dictionary where the first property points to the element in the linked list. Your insertion time will be linear though.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. I couldn't find a better solution. Thanks for your help!